# When trying to make a pong player, pressing the up key gives the error: one positional argument but two were given

Tags: python, tkinter, pong

I'm trying to make one of the players for pong, but whenever i try to move the player up (nahoru) or down(dolu), it tells me that nahoru() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given. When i try to add a second one it tells me that there's one missing.

```
from tkinter import*
class player1:

 def __init__ (self,a):
     self.a=a
     self.vzhled=self.a.platno.create_rectangle(30,110,40,190, fill="white")
     self.nahoru()
     self.dolu()
     self.a.okno.bind("<Up>",self.nahoru)
     self.a.okno.bind("<Down>",self.dolu)    

 def nahoru(self):      
      souradnice=self.a.platno.coords(self.vzhled)

      if (souradnice[1]<=0):
          self.dy=-10
          self.dx=0
          self.a.platno.move(self.vzhled,self.dx,self.dy)
          self.a.okno.after(85,self.nahoru)
```

Answer (score 0):

In functions called by a key event, `Tkinter` needs a local variable defining the event, which has to be put as a function parameter. For example, just add a variable `evt` in the definition of the function `nahoru` like this, even if you don't use this variable:

```py
def nahoru(self, evt):
```

The variable `evt` can give the mouse position, or the key pressed for example, depending on the type of event.

Do the same for the `dolu` function.